# Texmaker graphics

Tags: latex, pdflatex, texmaker

I have a problem with graphics in texmaker. I had my code in my old PC and it worked properly. But now in my new PC it doesnt work. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{elsarticle} % article for Elsevier
\usepackage{graphicx} % need this package

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp] % htbp stand for "here", "top", "bottom", "page"

\includegraphics[scale=1]{DATA/Zapoctovy program prvak/Matlab DU4/spy(H).jpg} 

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It says this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJzZh.png)

Comment: This was a temporary miktex problem. Try to update both in admin and user mode

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258780

Comment: Thanks, but I didnt find solution there. And it is updated, bucouse I download yesterday.

Comment: The problem was only resolved yesterday or so. Are you sure you have the newest version in both admin AND user mode?

Comment: Im not sure, im totally new in texmaker. What does admin and user mode mean? I just download Miktex 2.9 and Texmaker and both installed.

Comment: Miktex has two modes to update package, see https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console for a short guide on how to update. Remember you have to do this two times - once in each mode. (texmaker is just an editor and unrelated to the problem you face)