# pdfpages generating errors on newest version

Tags: latex, pdfpages

I tried recompiling my bachelor thesis in latex today and encountered problems with the pdfpages package. 
While it worked perfectly when I originally compiled the thesis it now throws "undefined control sequence" errors.
The new pdfpages package is "packaged on 24/09/2019".
Miktex console version is 2.9.7206

I tried compiling it with an old version I still had on my desktop pc which worked without a problem. After updating the miktex packages it stopped working there as well.
I also produced a minimal file which does nothing but trying to include a pdf file and this also produces the error. So it's not any other package or code I used in the thesis.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{test.pdf} %Use any pdf you want to try.

\end{document}
```

While on the old version it would work as expected including the pdf document in the output the updated package just throws the error "undefined control sequence" 6 times and a single "file filename.pdf not found" error.

Comment: Can you show the complete .log file?

Comment: I guess the main.log? 
Here you go.
https://pastebin.com/2k4sErsR

This is the log file generated by trying to compile the example above. 
Just the \usepackage and the \includepdf and the koma class.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a recent miktex problem: can you try to update both in user and admin mode? Sometimes also formats need to be rebuild

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258780/pdflatex-includegraphics-file-not-found

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Samcarter. Seems to be a temporary miktex problem with the graphicx package which is used in the background of \includepdf.
Thanks to all the other answers as well.

@Edit: 
True to Samcarters words the problem was not fixed for me.
After updating all the packages I had to rebuild the formats (miktex console -> settings -> formats -> rebuild (I rebuild latex, pdflatex, pdftex from user mode)
After that it worked fine again.

Comment: I just realized there were no other people involved. Even more thanks to Samcarter for your fast reaction!

Comment: (disclaimer: I don't use miktex myself, so I cannot test) If I understand the situation correctly, the issue should have been fixed. Can you update both in admin and user mode (it is important to do both updates) and try again?