# Latex doesn't find graphics after reinstall

Tags: latex

Okay so I've been developing this book with many extended unicode glyphs, and lots of pages of computer-generated content. All was going well until I added more graphics. Then I reached the memory limit of luaLaTeX (even though it is supposed to "dynamically allocate memory").

That started what amounts to arcane experimentation with LaTeX, trying to increaase the memory. It involved initexmf. Eventually I guess it all broke. I tried to reinstall mikTeX and now I can't compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%\includegraphics[]{C:/Users/Edrihan/PycharmProjects/wayOfChange/Graphics/FCircles/256px/BW/FCircle_2048_BW.png}
\includegraphics[]{example.jpg}
\end{document}
```

This gives me:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `C:/Users/Edrihan/PycharmProjects/wayOfChange/Graphics/FCir
cles/256px/BW/FCircle_2048_BW.png' not found on input line 4.


! Package luatex.def Error: File `"C:/Users/Edrihan/PycharmProjects/wayOfChange
/Graphics/FCircles/256px/BW/""FCircle_2048_BW".png' not found: using draft sett
ing.

See the luatex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 ...aphics/FCircles/256px/BW/FCircle_2048_BW.png}

?
```

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2019.10.15)  15 OCT 2019 17:42
 restricted system commands enabled.
**MWE.tex
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-08-11 2.67 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-08-11 2.67 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is G:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/luatex-cac
he/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2019-08-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
19-08-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 4
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.109”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 5
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is G:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/luatex-cac
he/generic/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.374 seconds
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from G:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/luat
ex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/10/08 v1.3c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 105.

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) (./MWE.aux)
\openout1 = MWE.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count88
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box27
\nofMPsegments=\count89
\nofMParguments=\count90
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count91
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count92
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count93
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) (g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
))))
(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)


(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks17
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 43
8.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG
,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live

))

LaTeX Warning: File `example.jpg' not found on input line 5.


! Package luatex.def Error: File `"""example".jpg' not found: using draft setti
ng.

See the luatex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \includegraphics[]{example.jpg}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[1

{g:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./MWE.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1561 strings out of 493864
 100000,106986 words of node,token memory allocated
 377 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 44 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:25,3:2,4:1,5:21,6:1,7:33,9:14
 6174 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 16 fonts using 598963 bytes
 46i,4n,30p,254b,116s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
<g:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf><g:/t
exlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono10-regular.otf>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 4897 bytes).

PDF statistics: 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: try to update miktex both in user and admin mode and rebuild the formats (probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342549/pdfpages-generating-errors-on-newest-version) If this does not help, show the complete .log file

Comment: Okay I edited my post to contain the log file. Note that this is after finally uninstalling mikTeX to attempt to try the same MWE with texlive. The result however is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the log file! Is this the log from the very same document shown in your question? The strange thing is that it seems to load additional packages like `grffile`.

Comment: As a test, can you try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{document}` This will tell use if the problem is related to the particular path or for images in general

Comment: I ran it like that and it didn't find the file again. One thing that I think I never saw before was that in the error message, the filename is weirdly quoted like this:

```Package luatex.def Error: File `"""example".jpg' not found: using draft setting. \includegraphics[]{example.jpg}```
That's a lot of quotes!

Comment: Just checking: do you actually have a file called `example.jpg` in your search tree? The `example-image` from my previous comment should be included in every tex distribution (as long as the `mwe` is installed, which is included in a full texlive installation by default)

Comment: (the error with the "weird" quotes is only the second message after `example.jpg` without so many quotes is not found.

Comment: Ok I feel really dumb now but I was using my own example and it was a png file. When I changed the extension it did work. I'm not sure what fixed it in end but it seems like my main file actually compiles again.