# Latex not compiling with graphics

Tags: graphics, latex

I am no longer able to compile any latex documents which contain graphics. Text only documents compile fine and the same documents with graphics compile without problem on my laptop but but not my desktop. I'm running Texmaker on Windows 7.

Mininal woring example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello
\includegraphics[]{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

All packages are updated, I have also tried out other document classes, I even downloaded a different editor (TexStudio) but it's the same issue. There seemed to be an issue with Miktex 8 months ago:
[Latex doesn't find graphics after reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368691/latex-doesnt-find-graphics-after-reinstall) but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Error message is below, the log file was nearly 3,000 characters, so too big to include here but I can include if needed.

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@tempa.<inserted text>\par<> ./MWE.texI suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing meto read past where you wanted me to stop.I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.! Emergency stop.<> ./MWE.tex (job aborted, no legal \end found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:17427 strings out of 480768338862 string characters out of 2892862581066 words of memory out of 300000033044 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000533243 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 3000000 for 90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 819158i,4n,67p,793b,281s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: a) can you reproduce the problem with `example-image`, which is available in most tex installations? b) can you show the complete .log file of your small test document?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer, beamer already loads it

Comment: Hi, thanks, I wasn't aware Beamer didn't need graphicx, problem persists with example-image. The log file even for this tiny bit of code is 2,800 words, it won't fit in a replya or an edit of the question

Comment: You could use https://pastebin.com/ or similar to share the log file

Comment: Thanks, posted it on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WKgYnVdR)

Comment: Thanks! One thing that looks a bit strange is that while the other packages seem to be fairly up to date, etoolbox is a bit old and also causes warnings from failed patches. Maybe you can try to update it

Comment: some other packages like geometry also seem to be not up to date

Comment: oh, and graphicx seems also outdated.

Comment: In short, can you try to update your tex distribution?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! For some reason these packages aren't updating then, In the Miktex console it says all packages are up to date. I tried updating through admin mode but that didn't work either, I get an error `log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly` Should I rather ask this as a different question?

Comment: A new question about the update problem seems to be a good idea. Maybe take it to tex.stackexchange.com, some of the users there use miktex